# Scraping the url of a webpage we are currently in

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I wanted to know if we can scrape the url of the webpage we are currently in?

For example, if i wanted to scrape the data from `scrapy.org`, then i can define rules to extract the data and the links provided within the page. But can i scrape the url `scrapy.org` itself as a `url` from that webpage? Since the url we are currently in will not be mentioned in the html file, is there a way to do this?

Here is the problem i am trying to solve:

I am trying to scrape the job description from [this](http://jobs.methodisthealthsystem.org/job/Richardson-MEDICAL-TECHNOLOGIST-Job-TX-75080/29136700/) webpage.

I would like to know if we can extract the hyperlink to that page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

In your parse code, you should have a `response` object, and `response.url` will be the url of the current page being scraped.

[Have a read of scrapy documentation for more details](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)